# Software to do a 3 way backup

Tags: backup, rdiff-backup

I am currently doing a backup of my system on an external hard disk using rdiff-backup. This kind of backup is good when the disk dies. However, I was also wondering if I can extend this method to do a 3 way backup? For example, instead of just backing up to one hard disk, I can back up to two hard disks. And everytime, before doing the backup, the program checks for integrity of files by comparing all the three copies, and then chooses the version which agrees on at least two hard disks. This way, I can take care of on disk corruption of my files too.

Is it possible with rdiff-backup? If not, does there exist some similar kind of utility?

Comment: Why not install software RAID1

Comment: Did not come to my mind, because I was always thinking in terms of backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd support the idea of @Miline to use RAID1 (or RAID5) for data integrity. For the 3-way backup, I'm using `rsnapshot` for creating incremental backups and `rsync` with `--delete` parameter to sync the backup over ssh to another system.